# Using dplyr to group and summarize timeseries data inside a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, time-series

Thanks in advance for the assistance. I know that there are similar questions but they are all simpler than the question being asked here as they deal with groupings by factor rather than by DateTime.

My goal is to write a function that can be applied to various physical parameters in an oceanic dataset (<100 columns). Each physical parameter is automatically recorded at a 30-minute interval and needs to be subjected to the same complex summary calculation.

The dataframe (df) looks like this:

```
dt                  par 1    par 2   par 3    par 100
2018-06-06 00:00    95.6      976    0.18     ...
2018-06-06 00:30    NA       1002    0.19     ...
2018-06-06 01:00    95.9     1019    0.20     ...
...
[regularly spaced data]
...
2018-10-31 23:00    72.4     887     NA       ...
2018-10-31 23:30    72.1     889     0.17     ...
```

I have code that will successfully make the needed calculations for a single parameter (1 column) of the data frame. To apply these calculations to other parameters requires copying and pasting the code and then changing the column name in that copied and pasted code. It seems that there is a better way to do this such as writing a function (which I have tried to do) or using data.frame (which I am trying to get better at and really have no idea if that would work). I have tried to write a function.

```
fun = function(df,dt, par){
df1=df %>% #new dataframe to temporarily store site specific calculations
  group_by(hour = cut(dt , breaks="60 min")) %>% #Cut data into 1-hour intervals
  summarize(x = mean(par)) #Calulated the average for each 1-hour interval 
df1$hour <- as.Date(df1$hour) #Remove time element from datetime so hourly averaged can be grouped by date
df.avg <- aggregate(df1$x, by=list(df1$hour), mean) #calculate daily average 
df.max <- aggregate(df1$x, by=list(df1$hour), max)  #calculate daily max 

#Temporary dataframe
date=as.data.frame(df.avg$Group.1) #used to calculate 7-day rolling mean
avg=as.data.frame(df.avg$x) #used to calculate 7-day rolling mean
max=as.data.frame(df.max$x) #used to calculate 7-day rolling mean

#7-day rolling mean (centered) of average daily mean temp
calc.avg=as.data.frame(cbind(date, (rollapply(avg,7,mean,align='center',fill=NA)))) 
#7-day rolling mean (centered) of average daily maximum temp
calc.max=as.data.frame(cbind(date, (rollapply(max,7,mean,align='center',fill=NA))))

#Identify maximum temperatures and date of occurence based on the 7-day running mean  calculation
df.avg=calc.avg[which.max(calc.avg$`df.avg$x`),]
df.max=calc.max[which.max(calc.max$`df.max$x`),]

#site-specific data as dataframe to be combined with all sites at end
calc=cbind(df.avg, df.max)
names(calc)=c("Date AVG", "Par AVG", "Date MAX", "Par Max")
nam=data.frame("Par 1 Summary")#                                                      
names(nam)="Location"
output=cbind(nam,calc) 
output}

par=df$Par1

fun(df,dt,par)
```

This does not work, I get an error message "argument is not numeric or logical". However, if in the summarise line of the function I replace the text par with `Par 1`, then get the output that I need. I think there may be a syntax related issue that I am not adhering to but can't figure out what it is.

The results I ultimately hope to get is a dataframe that contains the following information:

```
Parameter    Date of AVG    AVG     Date of MAX    MAX
Par 1        2018-07-21     99.9    2018-07-25     101.1
Par 2        2018-07-03     1005    2018-07-25     1081
Par 3        2018-07-20     0.29    2018-07-27     0.45
...
[Par 4 - 99]
...
Par 100      ...            ...     ...            ...
```

Comment: You can try setting `par <- "par 1"` and try it. The reason it doesn't work is because summarise is expecting a variable _name_ not `df$par`, which is the actual data itself. The reason it worked when you replaced it with `par 1` is because that `par 1` is an existing column name (summarise is happy with that).

Comment: Also, look into using `mutate_at` with `starts_with`. This will allow you do `fun` to all of your columns. Maybe something like `mutate_at(vars(starts_with("par")), funs(fun))`?

Comment: Setting par <- "Par 1" results in the same error. I am confused since functions should be adaptable and handle different parameters regardless of their name but the function I wrote will only work if the exact column name is specified rather than being more generic. I have seen code recommending the use of enquo(par) and then replacing par with !!par but I have not had luck with that as an approach.  Also I apologise but I am not sure I understand your second comment.  If needed, I'd be glad to share more of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, looking at your data it doesn't look like column `dt` is in date-time format. You need to convert in into `POSIXct` class before using `cut`. You can change initial part of your function to

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

df1 = df %>% group_by(new = cut(as.POSIXct(dt),
            format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", breaks="60 min")) %>%
            summarize(x = mean(!!sym(par), na.rm = TRUE))
```

If the rest part of the code is correct it should give the expected result as this converts literal string into symbol and then evaluates it. Also as far I could understand this function it works only for one column. Try using it for the first column as

```
fun(df, dt, "par1")
```

and check if you get the expected output. Now you need to do this for all the 100 columns which can be generated using `paste0` and applies using `lapply`/`map`

```
lapply(paste0("par ", 1:100), function(par) fun(df,dt,par))
```

This will generate a list of dataframes for you which you can bind together with `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0("par ", 1:100), function(par) fun(df,dt,par)))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I got an error message at first due to my dplyr package needing to be updated to work properly with the newest version of rlang but after that everything worked great.